# Rails AR: Most efficient way of writing a scope which requires several joins

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, performance

Consider the following

```
class Room < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :authorisations, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :authorised_users, through: :authorisations, source: :user

  scope :without_privacy_restriction, where(public: true)
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :rooms, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :accessible_rooms, through: :authorisations, source: :room
  has_many :authorisations
end
```

User can be a owner of a room, he can also be an authorised user in another user's room. Above all this, user can be defined as an admin (another column in the users table which represents this) and have access to all rooms no matter what.

I want to be able to write an efficient scope which returns back all accessible rooms to a given user, but I can't determine what's the most efficient way of achieving this.

Answer (score 0):

This is not actually a scope.

I'd make two things

```
class Room < ActiveRecord::Base

  class << self

    def accessible_by(user) # classmethods and scopes are interchangeable
      if user.admin?
        scoped # this returns "all" but not as an array, so you can chain
               # starting with rails4 you can use "all".
      else
        user.accessible_rooms
      end
    end

  end

end
```

This is to have a different scope returned when the user is admin or not. Then, to get owners in the same scopes, you could denormalize the "ownership" by adding an authorisation for owned rooms

```
class Room < ActiveRecord::Base

  after_create :authorise_owner

  def authorise_owner
    authorisations.create(user_id: owner_id)
  end

end
```

So you don't need to do strange joins.